# I am getting two Body Tags when Webpage is rendered

Tags: html, document-body

Very strange problem. This has been verified happening in FF, Chrome and IE. I have verified this happens when javascript is disabled.

My site is http://thehostwiz.com - this issue is happening on the site and has been for quite some time.

My current source html looks like this

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
```

This is the end result when I have a single body tag in my html (what's with the unknown character?).
http://thehostwiz.com/wp-content/uploads/extra-body-tag.png

When I comment out the Body Tag a body tag is added to the page. Probably the expected outcome when body tag is missing except this added body tag has that unknown character as well.

Is there some sort of cross site scripting or a hack or attack happening to my site?

Comment: Here is an additional image of the body tag commented out and an unknown character being added to the tag http://thehostwiz.com/wp-content/uploads/extra-body-ff-source.png

Comment: It would seem that your host is injecting its own html. I did go to the URL you posted, however, and I didn't see two body tags? Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably a WordPress thing. My guess would be something to do with your theme -- but that's a stab in the dark.

Comment: Make sure your theme uses some of the required wordpress tags. Include `<?php wp_title(); ?>` between `<title>` and `</title>` also be sure to have `<?php wp_head(); ?>`  right before `</head>` same with the wp footer tag

Comment: Also check your header.php and footer.php files for anything odd and missing, or added, like body tag in header as well as one in the index.php file, etc. etc.

Comment: So the theme has definitely been ruled out. I have just uploaded and activated the twentyeleven theme and loaded the theme I was using onto another server. I have also deactivated all of the plugins. I really dont believe this was a wordpress issue or I would have posted else where in a wordpress forum, but I guess something could be going on with the database (sql injection maybe?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up transferring all of my files and my database to another server. There I found my files and database were not the issue. I also noticed this odd behavior happening on other sub directory installs of Wordpress on the same hosting account. I tried to pressure my host into finding the issue but they insisted it wasn't a hosting issue.

To resolve the problem I asked them to shut my hosting down and allow me to move to another hosting account. Although no actual fix was found for the problem I no longer have this issue. Thanks for the input and comments on my Original Post.